# How to set a SimpleAdapter to AutoCompletetextview?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In my application, I need show the Item more information for the AutoCompletetextview.
How can I set the SimpleAdapter to AutoCompletetextview rather than a ArrayAdapter?